# zeromq installation python node and electron

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, npm, installation, zeromq

I have this error trying to work with zeromq, i dont know what is, i installed everything but the error keeps!

````
Los proyectos de esta solución se van a compilar de uno en uno. Para habilitar la compilación en paralelo, agregue el modificador "-m".
D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(382
,5): error MSB8020: The build tools for Visual Studio 2015 (Platform Toolset = 'v140') cannot be found. To build using
the v140 build tools, please install Visual Studio 2015 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Vis
ual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution". [C:
\Users\MAATTZ\Desktop\electron-python-example-master\node_modules\zeromq\build\zmq.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:196:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:203:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
gyp ERR! command "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\MAATTZ\Desktop\electron-python-example-master\node_modules\zeromq
gyp ERR! node -v v12.8.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! zeromq@4.6.0 install: `node scripts/prebuild-install.js || (node scripts/preinstall.js && node-gyp rebuild)`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the zeromq@4.6.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\MAATTZ\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-07T03_27_46_759Z-debug.log```
````

Comment: You need to install Build Tools from Visual Studio 2015 that can be found here https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48159

Comment: Actually i have installed it